# Populating a CSV with uniform distribution of values

Tags: python, performance, csv

I want to write a python script to populate a CSV file based on the columns and each column has a preset list of strings that can only be in the column.

**Example**:

For column 'name' the only possible values are 'Andrew', 'James', 'Steve', 'Charlie' etc. and in a similar way each of the other columns have a preset list of possible values.

I'd like to populate a the CSV in the most uniform distribution as possible so that there are rows of diverse combinations of column values.

**Question:**

1. Should I use lists and randomly select values?
2. Will it cause redundancies?
3. Are there any better ways of doing it?

Comment: What do you mean by "redundancies"? If you're talking about duplicates, then, if the list of names is finite and then amount of values to be generated is greater than then number of names, there will most definitely be duplicate entries.

Comment: sounds like a job for faker: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-faker-library/ that is exactly for making fake data like names or addresses and it is even customizable for whatever you need

Comment: You can use the `random.choice()` in the `random` library or you can read up more on numpy's random choice [link](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should help get you started:

```
import csv
import random

with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
    csv_output.writerow(["Name", "Age"])

    names = ["Andrew", "Steve", "Charlie"]

    for _ in range(10):     # Create 10 entries
        name = random.choice(names)
        age = random.randint(20, 50)

        csv_output.writerow([name, age])
```

Giving you a sample output such as:

```
Name,Age
Andrew,50
Steve,37
Charlie,34
Andrew,47
Andrew,28
Andrew,27
Charlie,29
Charlie,49
Steve,42
Charlie,38
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked, I also used faker as well for some data.